# Can't create an Azure WebJob: telling me the "triggered" folder already exists, but it is doesn't

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I'm not able to create an Azure WebJob. Trying to create a WebJob in the Management Portal throws an error and when trying to manually create the necessary files it tells me the following error message:

[image: error message running the command in debug console]

I have no idea how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the error by scaling the app plan up and scaling it back to the old plan.